# how to stop reloading the page when downloading an image using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, file, download

I'm trying to download an image from URL and the page reloads and I will be disconnected from my socket server

is there any way to download a file without reloading the page
and also with out using target="_blank"

```
 const downloadImage = () => {
    const a = document.createElement("a"); 
      a.href = message.downloadImageUrl;
      a.download = "downlaodImage";
      a.click();   
  };
```

Comment: @Yogi thanks for answering but I don't want to go to a new page either sorry forgot to mention it in the question

Comment: From your description of the problem we can assume that the image is stored cross domain.  And I'm not aware of a way to download an image cross domain unless CORS is enabled.  Even if you were to capture the image as a dataURL, the browser would still mark it as unsecure and refuse to download it.